# FAT deleted files recovery capability

Tags: filesystems, recovery, data-recovery, fat, file-recovery

I was working on kinda exploration of File Allocation Table recovery last couple of weeks. My purpose is to locate a possibly deleted file by its signature (for example, ZIP file by "50 4B 03 04" bytes) and recover the whole thing to search inside of it.

I've explored there's a problem with FAT: file system uses allocation table indicies for both cluster chain storing and deleted files marking, making files recovery, at first sight, impossible.

But there's hell of a recovery software advertising promising recovery of files deleted from FAT file system. So, there might be a workaround, I assume.

I've found that we can successfully recover files continuously located on disk. First cluster gives us an index, and index address value gives us strong possiblity of finding a directory entry where file size is stored. But is it the end? I'd like to recover fragmented files as well, but can't find the way.

May anyone know a workaround and help me here a bit, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT file system uses a directory entry for each file and folder. It shows starting cluster, filename, date and size. To access file, system looks in directory finds file and notes the starting cluster. Then it goes to the FAT (file allocation table) cluster that corresponds to the starting cluster. The starting cluster entry contains the cluster number of the next cluster. The next cluster entry points to the next cluster and so on until you come to an  end of file marker which means this is the last cluster used by the file.

When you delete a file or folder. It locates the directory it resides in and changes the 1st letter of the file or folder name entry to E6 hex (not sure if its E6 or something slightly different) and it deletes the FAT chain.

That is why you can recover only contiguous files in FAT system once  a file is deleted. All data recovery utilities will use this method. None other available unless you can find traces of the FAT with correct cluster chains still in place.

Comment: Well, that's not what I was waiting for, but looks like it's a sad truth. Thank you.